# Read .csv table and print it as SQL query output

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using a bastardised version of T-SQL to generate reports about information within a database driven CAD software (Solidworks Electrical). I am trying to generate a Table of Contents. Due to limitations within the software, I have to generate this table using SQL.

What I would like to do is create the Table of Contents in Excel, save it as a .csv, and have my SQL query read this file and spit it out as an output.

Example Table:

```
Sheet,System
1,Radios
2,Processors
3,Navigation
```

After some searching I've been unable to find a solution myself. My problems are:

1) Read a .csv file stored on my harddrive

2) Turn this .csv file into a table (cant get stored on the database, is just temporary while we run the query)

3) Output the data in this table as the results of the query

I have tried to use the following to read my .csv table, but recieve the error "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error". So it's possible my software just won't allow me to read external files. (NB, my software uses ]] [[ instead of quotes....)

```
select 
]]col1[[,
]]col2[[,
]]col3[[
from openrowset('MSDASQL'
,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}'
,'select * from D:\SQL Queries\input.CSV')
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sql works for me:

```
select * from openrowset (bulk N'C:\Temp\source.csv', formatfile = N'C:\Temp\format.xml', firstrow=2) SourceFile
```

Content of **source.csv** is this:

```
Sheet,System
1,Radios
2,Processors
3,Navigation
```

Content of **format.xml** is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=","/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="128" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="ID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```